# Yii, CActiveDataProvider, subquery from

Tags: sql, yii, postgresql

Как сделать вот такой запрос для CActiveDataProvider, БД PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) * FROM items WHERE param = 5) sq ORDER BY sq.id
```

Думаю запрос нужно сделать таким, потому что если сделать вот так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) * FROM items WHERE param = 5 ORDER BY id
```

Postgres выдаст ошибку, что надо в ORDER BY добавить name, и если добавить, то сортировка будет происходить только по полю name

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. В Postgres создал представление:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) * FROM items
```

Создал новый ActiveRecord и в tableName() указал название представления.
Т.к в представлениях нет ключей, первичный ключ добавил в модель вот так:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $shcema = $this->getTableSchema();
    $shcema->primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Comment: Dima Gvozdev: Борьба с фреймворком увенчалась созданием представления. На вашем месте, я бы воспользовался [Query Builder-ом/DBAL](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.query-builder)

Comment: Фильтрация по другим параметрам собирается в CDbCriteria. переделывать все для Query Builder-а не очень хочется, да и представление использует CActiveDataProvider. С представлением код практически не изменился, а в базе представление создать - 5 минут)

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) * FROM items WHERE param = 5 ORDER BY name, id
```

ЗЫ Для CActiveDataProvider в любом случае придется писать запрос текстом, т.к. `...distinct on(expr)..` оно не умеет.